# A query on background service

Tags: android, service, android-asynctask

In my project I plan to launch a background service on a user action.
My question is:

1. As background service's life cycle is not associated to calling
   component's life, so if android kills calling component while
   service is still running then what would happen if a communication
   has to be done between service and component.
2. If calling activity is killed and hence user has no UI to work with,then how can user kill background service if he/she wants to.
3. Async task runs on a separate thread so that it doesn't interfere UI thread.Service runs on same thread as UI then why is interference issue not a concern issue in case of service?

With regards
Manish

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. If activity is killed then activity must unbind service. So service will be notified that activity unbinding. You could create a notification when Activity is killed or (not recommended) you could start activity from service.
2. If service is useless when UI not visible, it's better if you stop service when Activity unbinding. User can't stop service, you have to provide an UI to kill service.
3. Please explain more

Comment: Thanks Laurent.What I plan is to have a background service which would get location updates and would validate new location with user supplied location...and if validation is successful then notify user about it.So I plan to have a starting activity with UI which enables user to input location and then launch the service, and just forget it.My concern is that if android would kill starting activity, then what would service notify to when validation finally is successful.If service is notified when activity unbinds, how does it help me with my objective as it needs someone to talk to.